# Dynamic Dialogue button with ICS

Tags: android, dynamic, button

I've been digging around for a while now and i can't seem to find a real solution to this.

I've made a custom dialog box for when someone chooses an item off a list view it populates content from strings dynamically. Now when i made an alertbuilder box i could just use .setNeutralButton to work and it would make the button look native in different versions of android.

Now with the custom Dialog i can't seem to do the same thing, i currently end up having to use xml to assign the button and it just looks like a grey block with text rather then the nice borderless buttons 4.0 assigns.

I'm assuming there is some easy way to do this and i'm just not looking in the right places.

Any help would be awesome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trick for ICS borderless buttons: [How to make a proper button bar on ICS](https://gist.github.com/2348305)
i hope it would solve your problem.